# Interface specifies methods

Tags: java, methods, interface

Write an interface named Nameable that specifies the following methods:

```
public void setName(String n)
public String getName()
```

This is what I got:

```
 public interface Nameable{     
     public void setName(String n){         
                n =name;     }    
        public String getName() {
                  return n;    } }
```

is this correct or is there a better way of doing this??

Answer (score 6):

An interface doesn't specify implementation, so no, this isn't correct.

You must separate the definition of the available methods (the interface) and the implementation (the class) :

```
public interface Nameable{     
     public void setName(String n); 
     public String getName();
}

public class Named implements Nameable {
      private String name;
      public void setName(String n){         
          this.name = n;
     }    
     public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't define a method in your interface, you only declare them. A class which implements that interface later on, provides the implementation of the method.

> is this correct or is there a better way of doing this??

Better way? Yes. Copy this code and paste in your favorite IDE. It will tell you where you are wrong, with so many `Red-Marks`.

IDE like `Eclipse` suddenly starts screaming if you create such an interface, and you can tell it to correct it for you. Then you can see the magic.

Answer (score 0):

You must remember that interfaces only provide method declarations, and do not provide implementation. That is up to the implemented class.

```
public interface Nameable
{  
     public void setName(String n);
     public String getName();
}
public class NameableImplmentation implments Nameable
{
     public void setName(String n)
     {         
         //insert code    
     }    
     public String getName() 
     {
         //insert code
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will gives you `Abstract methods do not specify a body`.

all the methods of interface are by default `abstract`, and abstract method has no body, see here [abstract](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Keywords/abstract)

An `interface` is a group of related methods with **empty bodies**, but in your code all the methods having the body so that will not compile, see [how interface work](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)

more on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_%28Java%29)